# Adjusting for multiple comparisons of simple effects in a continuous x categorical design

Tags: r, multiple-regression, interaction, multiple-comparisons

I am interested in a design that involves a continuous dependent variable (`Y`) that is modeled as a function of a continuous variable (`X`) in interaction with a categorical variable (`group`) that has three levels. My interest focuses on the simple effect of `X` on `Y` for each `group`. However, I don't have any prior hypotheses and would like to explore and compare the three effects of `X` (one for each group level). Assuming the `X` x `group` interaction is significant, my main concern is how should I correct for multiple comparisons in this case?

For example (in R):

```r
# Simulate some data
set.seed(1)
n <- 18
DF <- data.frame(X = rnorm(n),
                 group = gl(3, n/3, labels = LETTERS[1:3]))
DF$Y <- dplyr::case_when(DF$group == "A" ~ 1 + 2*DF$X + rnorm(n/3),
                     DF$group == "B" ~ 3 + 4*DF$X + rnorm(n/3),
                     DF$group == "C" ~ 5 + 6*DF$X + rnorm(n/3))

#              X group          Y
# 1  -0.62645381     A  0.5683136
# 2   0.18364332     A  1.9611880
# 3  -0.83562861     A  0.2477201
# 4   1.59528080     A  4.9726979
# 5   0.32950777     A  1.7335805
# 6  -0.82046838     A -2.6302885
# 7   0.48742905     B  5.5695420
# 8   0.73832471     B  5.8971701
# 9   0.57578135     B  5.1473299
# 10 -0.30538839     B  0.3076941
# 11  1.51178117     B  8.5689746
# 12  0.38984324     B  4.9773145
# 13 -0.62124058     C  2.6312361
# 14 -2.21469989     C -8.3909871
# 15  1.12493092     C 12.1372571
# 16 -0.04493361     C  4.6765933
# 17 -0.01619026     C  3.5257989
# 18  0.94383621     C 10.2480227
```

I beginning by testing main effects and interactions with orthogonal contrasts:

```r
# Orthogonal contrasts
mdl_ortho <- lm(Y ~ X * group, data = DF, contrasts = list(group = contr.sum))
summary(mdl_ortho)
#             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
# (Intercept)   2.9170     0.2769  10.534 2.04e-07 ***
# X             4.2411     0.3238  13.097 1.81e-08 ***
# group1       -1.7052     0.3638  -4.687 0.000526 ***
# group2       -0.3333     0.4410  -0.756 0.464451    
# X:group1     -1.8439     0.4242  -4.347 0.000950 ***
# X:group2      0.1634     0.5467   0.299 0.770062   

car::Anova(mdl_ortho, type = 3)
#              Sum Sq Df F value    Pr(>F)    
# (Intercept) 111.122  1 110.965 2.036e-07 ***
# X           171.784  1 171.543 1.813e-08 ***
# group        42.238  2  21.090 0.0001181 ***
# X:group      34.436  2  17.194 0.0002997 ***
# Residuals    12.017 12
```

So there is a main effect of `X` (`b=4.23, F=172, p<.001`), a main effect of `group` (`F=21, p<.001`), and a `X:group` interaction (`F=17, p<.001`).
Next I want to test the simple effects of `X` and see if they differ across the levels of `group`. To do so I rely on Dummy codes.

```r
mdl_A <- lm(Y ~ X * group, data = DF, contrasts = list(group = contr.treatment(1:3, base = 1)))
summary(mdl_A)
#             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
# (Intercept)   1.2118     0.4088   2.964 0.011823 *  
# X             2.3972     0.4746   5.051 0.000284 ***  (simple effect of X for group A)
# group2        1.3720     0.7215   1.901 0.081522 .  
# group3        3.7437     0.5802   6.453 3.15e-05 ***
# X:group2      2.0073     0.8984   2.234 0.045260 *  
# X:group3      3.5244     0.6015   5.860 7.72e-05 ***

mdl_B <- lm(Y ~ X * group, data = DF, contrasts = list(group = contr.treatment(1:3, base = 2)))
summary(mdl_B)
#             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
# (Intercept)   2.5837     0.5946   4.345 0.000952 ***
# X             4.4046     0.7628   5.774 8.83e-05 ***  (simple effect of X for group B)
# group1       -1.3720     0.7215  -1.901 0.081522 .  
# group3        2.3717     0.7232   3.279 0.006586 ** 
# X:group1     -2.0073     0.8984  -2.234 0.045260 *  
# X:group3      1.5170     0.8476   1.790 0.098743 . 

mdl_C <- lm(Y ~ X * group, data = DF, contrasts = list(group = contr.treatment(1:3, base = 3)))
summary(mdl_C)
#             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
# (Intercept)   4.9555     0.4117  12.036 4.68e-08 ***
# X             5.9216     0.3695  16.026 1.82e-09 ***  (simple effect of X for group C)
# group1       -3.7437     0.5802  -6.453 3.15e-05 ***
# group2       -2.3717     0.7232  -3.279  0.00659 ** 
# X:group1     -3.5244     0.6015  -5.860 7.72e-05 ***
# X:group2     -1.5170     0.8476  -1.790  0.09874 .
```

My questions are:

1. For each simple effect of `X`, do I need to adjust the *p-value* to test if they are significantly different from zero (e.g., by multiplying them by 3)? I'm talking about `A:p=0.000284`, `B:p=8.83e-05`, and `C:p=1.82e-09`.
2. How can I test if each simple effect *significantly* differs or not from the others? Basically we have `AvsB:p=0.081522`, `AvsC:p=3.15e-05`, and `BvsC:p=0.00659`. My guess is that I also have to adjust these *p-values* to correct for multiple comparison, but how? (by multiplying them by 3?).

Bonus question: If we do have to correct the *p-values*, is there a function in R that facilitates this procedure? Also, it would help me a lot if you have any reference where they do report these kind of analyses.

Comment: In R, use p.adjust(c(0.000284,8.83e-05,1.82e-09,3.15e-05,3.15e-05,0.00659),method="bonferroni"). Check the unadjusted p-values again because you repeated one of them: 3.15e-05. If this was the only 6 hypotheses you were ever considering testing, then this would be one valid way of controlling the familywise error rate for this family of these six hypotheses.

Comment: @JohnL Thanks for the input. I corrected the *p-value*. As for the adjustement, I feel that my hypotheses from question 1 (simple effects against 0) are independent from question 2 (interactions). Would it make sense if I adjust each set of hypotheses independently?

Comment: Yes, depending on how you would test these hypotheses if you did not already know the results. If you were always planning to test the second family only in the case where all the hypotheses in the first family were rejected, then you can test the second family sequentially. If you were planning to test the second group of hypotheses regardless, then all 6 need to be adjusted simultaneously.

Comment: Makes sense, thanks for the clarification. Now what if my plan was to first test the "interaction family" of hypothesis, and it turns out that there is only one significant  interaction (after adjustment), that points to a difference in simple effects of `X` in group A vs. B. Next I want to test the two simple effects (against 0) for group A and B given that this is the only significant difference between simple effects. Would it be correct if I adjust these two p-values by 2 (i.e. `p.adjust(pval1, pval2, method = "bonferroni")`)? Also, feel free to submit an answer and I will validate it.

Comment: You are getting into more complicated things like if this happens then do this, if that happens, then do that. There are ways to do that. For example see the R package [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gMCP/vignettes/gMCP.pdf) and the references.